# setinterval function skips interval

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to retrieve data from facebook and display it on my webpage.I am using the setInterval function to iterate through loop of images but the loop runs correct only for first attempt for the rest it skips most data. 
Below the code I'm using,

```
   function loop(){

    //console.log("l"+l);
      //i++;
     //window.clearTimeout(timer);
      if(posts!=i){

              i++;
      len=response.albums.data[i].photos.data.length;
      console.log("photos count:"+len);
      console.log("i:"+i);

      var interval1=window.setInterval(function(){
          $('#cf').hide();
          $('#libtn').hide();
          console.log("j:"+j)
          image= document.createElement('img');
          image.src= response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].picture;
          document.getElementById('imgs').innerHTML='<img src="'+image.src+'">';
          $('#imgs').hide();
          likes=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].likes.summary.total_count;
          document.getElementById('likes').style.textAlign="center";
          document.getElementById('likes').innerHTML=likes+"Likes";
          $('#likes').hide();
          response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.total_count;
          length=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.summary.total_count;
          document.getElementById('name').innerHTML="";
          document.getElementById('comment').innerHTML="";
          document.getElementById('circle2').innerHTML="";
          for(var k=0;k<length;k++){

              var pro='/'+response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].from.id+'/picture';
              FB.api(pro,'GET',{"type":"small"},
                      function(response) {

                          im=document.createElement('img');
                          im.src=response.data.url;
                          document.getElementById('circle2').innerHTML='<img src="'+im.src+'">'+"<br />";


              }
              );

             cmt=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].message;
             name=response.albums.data[i].photos.data[j].comments.data[k].from.name;
             document.getElementById('name').innerHTML=name+":";
             $('#name').hide();
             document.getElementById('comment').innerHTML=cmt;
             $('#comment').hide();
                         }  
             $('#cf').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#circle2').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#name').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#comment').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#imgs').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#likes').hide().fadeIn(1000);
             $('#libtn').hide().fadeIn(1000);

            j++;
           // m++;
            count++;
            console.log("count"+count+"len"+len);
           // alert("came here");
         // mydis();
          if(count==len){
             console.log("set interval");
             j=0;
             count=0;
             window.clearInterval(interval1);
             }

  },5000);                   
      calls--;
      /*if(calls==0){
          console.log("set interval1");
           window.clearInterval(interval); 
           }*/
      j=0;
      count=0;
      l=(response.albums.data[i].photos.data.length)*5000;
      console.log("l:"+l);
      window.setTimeout(loop,l);
     }//,60000);

  }
  if(calls!=0){
  console.log("here");
  loop();}
```

and the console output is:

```
 photos count:5
 i:0
 l:25000
 j:0
 count1len5
 j:1
 count2len5
 j:2
 count3len5
 j:3
 count4len5
 j:4
 count5len5
 set interval
 photos count:1
 i:1
 l:5000
 j:0
 count1len1
 set interval
 photos count:1
 i:2
 l:5000
 j:0
 count1len1
 set interval
 photos count:4
 i:3
 l:20000
 j:0
 count1len4
 j:1
 count2len4
 j:2
 count3len4
 FB.login() called when user is already connected
 here
 photos count:5
 i:0
 l:25000
 j:0
 count1len5
 photos count:1
 i:1
 l:5000
 j:0
 count1len1
 set interval
```

As you can see the second call of Fb.Login() makes setinterval function skip 4 images.Can anyone help me with solving this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you calling FB.login multiple times in the first place? Makes no sense.

Comment: to get latest data each 60sec

Comment: What does FB.login have to do with getting data? It handles the login part only.

Comment: even if i change that to album() (function that gets images,likes comments from facebook) still it shows same issue @CBroe

Comment: am using to check whether user is still logged in or not.But now I have changed it